# Recreating a removed view in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The View.remove() function in backbone js removes the container element of the view itself from the DOM preventing from recreating views that have been removed. Any idea how this scenario is handled

Here is my code,

```
var AttributeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#attrs"),
        template:_.template($('#attrs-template').html()),

        initialize:function() {
        },


        render:function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
            },

        dispose:function(eventName){
            this.unbind();
            this.remove();
        },

    });


var attrView = new AttributeView();
....
attrView.dispose();
//Later on some event I do the below
attrView = new AttributeView()
attrView.render();
```

The last two lines above do not recreate the view as the div with id="attrs" is not longer there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, you don't need your `dispose` method, the standard `remove` is sufficient:

```
var attrView = new AttributeView();
//....
attrView.remove();  // <--------- Do this instead
//...
attrView = new AttributeView()
attrView.render();
```

Secondly, you can override [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) if the standard version doesn't do what you need. The [default implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L1020) simply removes `this.el` and cleans up some event listeners:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},
```

In your case, you want to undo everything that `render` does and that means clearing out the HTML *inside* `this.el` and removing the events by calling [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents):

```
remove: function() {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.$el.empty();
    this.stopListening();
    return this;
},
```

Then you can call `attrView.remove()` and kill it off and `(new AttributeView()).render()` to bring it back.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Pu9a2/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for some reason code similar to your example does'nt work. I created the http://jsfiddle.net/EnVmN/7/ to illustrate the problem I have. Any idea what I am doing wrong. I am reusing your AttributeView  but added ItemView and trying to show and remove the attributeview on click of edit and remove icons respectively.

Comment: @mzafer: A view's events only work on the view's `el` and its children, your ItemView was rendering into `#items` but that wasn't ItemView's `el` so the click events on your icons weren't being sent to the ItemView: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KjC6x/

Comment: A year later and you're still saving lives - thanks for this. Been at it all afternoo :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LayoutManager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager) for Backbone Views, which understands that when you remove a view (parent - in the containment sense and not object-hierarchy sense), its subViews should also be removed.