# Removing view from DOM in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I searched and found some clues of how to remove view from DOM such as [Zombie RUN!](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) and the others post. After that I chose one of them to do [here the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966440/recreating-a-removed-view-in-backbone-js).

Here is my view :

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
       myCart1.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
       window.localStorage.setItem("User",serializeObjToJSON(customer));
   },
   el: '#webbodycontainer',
   events : {
       "click #addToCart" :  function(){
           myCart1.addToCart(newItem);
           myCart1.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
           $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
       }
   },
   render : function(){
       this.$el.html(homePanel);
       $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
   },
    remove: function() {
        this.undelegateEvents();
        this.$el.empty();
        this.stopListening();
        return this;
    }
});
return HomeView;
```

And this is my router :

```
app_router.on('route:home', function( ){
    var homeView = new HomeView();
    homeView.remove();
    homeView = new HomeView();
    homeView.render();
 });
```

But the view still stay in my DOM. Any idea about this issue please. Thanks.

Comment: You're removing it before inserting to DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
app_router.on('route:home', function( ){
    var homeView = new HomeView();
    homeView.remove();
    homeView = new HomeView();
    homeView.render();
 });
```

In line #3, you're calling `remove()` method. In line #4 you are instantiating it again and in line #5, you're inserting in the DOM.

You've to call `remove` after `render`. However, if you immediately call remove, you may not see anything in DOM. Below is an example of removing elements from DOM, when clicked on it

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
.....
   events : {
       "click #addToCart" :  function(){
           myCart1.addToCart(newItem);
           myCart1.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
           $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
       },
       'click': 'remove'
   },
......
});
```

Now, you can render it as follows:

```
app_router.on('route:home', function( ){
    var homeView = new HomeView();
    homeView.render();
 });
```

You now should see the elements on the page. When you click on them, they should be removed.

Comment: So where should I call the `remove()` function of my `HomeView`?

Comment: in my code, you see that i've added `'click': 'remove'` line. You can call remove method from anywhere else as long as you've the `homeView` variable in your context.

Comment: I also omitted `this.$el.empty();` from my function.

Comment: `#addToCart` button works only once in `HomeView` :/