# How to correctly remove whatever is necessary from backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Hey my attempt to remove everything was calling the close function in the search view file after triggering the previous or next functions with this.close() but it was removing the view completely affecting the navigate function... I was wondering how to go about removing everything after it is completed, otherwise the vent.on occurs multiple times in the router.

Here is my router file:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/page',
    'models/search',
    'views/search',
    'text!templates/search.html',
    'models/song',
    'text!templates/song.html'


], function($, _, Backbone, PageV, SearchM, SearchV, SearchT, SongM, SongT) { 
    var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
    var currentView, page, search;
    Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();
        if (this.onClose) { 
            this.onClose();
        }
    };

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({
        routes: {
            'page/:id': 'showPage',
            'search': 'showView' 
        }
    });

    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router, songPages;
        app_router = new AppRouter;

        vent.on('loadPage', function (id) {
            console.log('hit loaded page');
            var newPage = 'page/' + id;
            if(id < songPages && id >= 0 ) {
                app_router.navigate(newPage, true);
            } else {
                app_router.navigate('search', true);
            }

        })
        console.log('router file hit');
        app_router.on('route:showPage', function (id) {
            console.log('page rendered');
            var songs, collected, songM, start;
            songM = new SongM();
            songM.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
            songM.localStorage.findAll().forEach(function (i) {
                collected = i;
            });
            songPages = Math.ceil(collected.music.length / 25); //10 pages
            start = id * 25;
            songs = collected.music.splice(start, 25); 
            var titles = {
                week: collected.week,
                year: collected.year,
                channel: collected. channel
            };
            var currentId = parseInt(id);
            if (page) {console.log('page is current'); console.log(page); page.remove(); }
            page = new PageV({model: songM, collection: songs, vent: vent, titles: titles, theId: currentId });

            page.render(id);
            //$("#Sirius").html(page.el);


        });

        app_router.on('route:showView', function () {
            console.log('search page loading...');
            var cur;
            var searchM = new SearchM();
            //if (search) {console.log(search); search.remove(); }
            search = new SearchV({model: searchM, vent: vent}); 
            //if(cur) {cur.stopListening(); cur.remove(); console.log('cur removed'); }

            search.render();
            //cur = search;
            vent.on('nextPage', printCons);
            function printCons () {
                console.log('changing pages');
                app_router.navigate('page/0', true);
            };          
        });

        Backbone.history.start();

    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Here is the page with the page view:

```
  define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/song',
  'collections/songs',
  'views/song',
  'text!templates/page.html',
  'text!templates/song.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, Song, Songs, SongV, PageT, SongT){ 

  var Page = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#Sirius"),
    events: { 
      "click .prev": "previous",
      "click .next": "next"
    },

    previous: function () {
       this.options.vent.trigger('loadPage', this.options.theId - 1);
    },
    next: function () {
       this.options.vent.trigger('loadPage', this.options.theId + 1);
    },
    render: function () {
      var headings = this.options.titles; 
      var info = {
        week: headings.week,
        channel: headings.channel,
        year: headings.year
      }
      var pagetemp = _.template( PageT, info);
      this.$el.html( pagetemp );
      var songColl = this.collection;
      var songV = new SongV({collection: songColl});
      songV.render();

    }


  });
    return Page;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you re-use the same DOM element, `#Sirius`, each time you create a view.  On initialization, Backbone views delegate DOM events to the their top level node, wrapped with `$el`.

On removing the view, cleanup is automatic, as the node is removed from the DOM.  As you're replacing the HTML of the node without removing it, the event handlers are never removed, keeping your old views around responding to click events even after their content is no longer in the DOM.

There are a few ways to handle this.

1. When rendering replaceable content, don't render directly into a DOM element. Rather, treat it as a container and render inside it.  This way you can remove the view without affecting the original DOM.  This is a common approach for page regions with swappable views.

   ```
   // somewhere in a higher scope, refer to the page.  Note that if you
   // don't need to do any cleanup (Events bindings, model cleanup, etc), you
   // don't *need* to keep this reference.
   var page;

   // in your show handler, replace the *contents* of the DOM element rather 
   // than creating a 2nd view attached to it.  This means removing the `el`
   // from the view prototype, as well.
   if (page) page.remove();
   page = new Page(...);
   page.render();
   $("#Sirius").html(page.el);
   ```
2. Re-use the same view, updating its instance variables instead of replacing it.  This makes particular sense for pagination, where you're iterating over a collection of content but the structure remains the same.

   ```
   // somewhere in a higher scope (or on app.page, etc)
   var page;

   // on the view, clean up the process of "updating" settings with a method,
   // something like:
   update: function (options) {
     this.model = options.model;
     this.collection = options.collection;
     this.options = options;
   }

   // then in your show handler, create a new view the first time, then just
   // update it rather than replacing it
   page || (page = new PageV());
   page.update(options);
   ```
3. Clean up the delegated event bindings from the DOM element.  I hesitate to add this as both 1 and 2 are more appropriate, but any of these approaches would probably work:

   ```
   // kludge level 1: reference the searchview and attempt to clean it
   if (page) {
     page.undelegateEvents();
     page.stopListening(); // if available
     // any other cleanup
   }
   page = new PageV(...);

   // kludge level 2: unbind all DOM events from the element
   $("#Sirius").off();
   var page = new PageV(...);

   // kludge level 3: replace the element in the DOM
   $("#Sirius").replaceWith('<div id="#Sirius" />');
   var page = new PageV(...);
   ```

Don't do #3.  1 or 2 are far more appropriate.

Comment: Am I going to need to ever remove the views and models though? For example the search view? because someone can go back to the search view too by going to it's route and then wouldn't that create a duplicate view?

Comment: So I updated the code above as you can see to your refactored answer with some tweaks to pass in id and the logic of loading the page... however, I am still experiencing multiple views seeming to load as i go through the next and previous buttons, the page number jumps but ends up showing the correct number after a couple different numbers showing up, and the more i click the longer it takes. Also, when I get to the point where it takes me back to search, the search button does not work because of the multiple views problem...

Comment: I have a live example that you can see by going to lgavra.com/music#search

Comment: I updated the answer to solve your current problem.  As updated code reflects my first answer, I removed my initial recommendations.

Comment: I am kind of confused as to what you are referring too, first off there is no searchView there is a search which equates to SearchV and there is also a page view which is equates to PageV... and for number 1 I am rendering the template in the render function and I tried adding el just doesnt let the page load, and included the if statement... and not sure how to implement number 2

Comment: When I wrote `searchView` I was referring to the currently rendered instance of `PageV`.  Not sure why I prefixed it with search.  You're calling it `page` so I changed it to that.  The point of #1 is that you're rendering the view into an unattached (created by backbone) element, then attaching that element to the #Sirius div.  This way you can simply remove the view and append another one, without removing the #Sirius div.  It should work pretty much exactly as written, just remove the `el` from the view's definition (as the view should create its own el).

Comment: As for #2, it should work more or less as is.  Add that `update` method to the view definition then instead of creating a new page with the options each time you load a page, you `update` the existing page with the options.  `options` in my example would be your built options that you're initializing the page with (model, theId, etc)

Comment: I updated the code with method #1 but when I click on search the page shows no results, I updated my code to include the changes you mentioned... but on the pageview itself when it is being rendered this is being called to render the template this.$el.html( pagetemp ); so not sure if you want me to edit that instead of doing this $("#Sirius").html(page.el);

Comment: Also, I tried method #2, what is being passed in as options in the route handler because it is undefined, and if I declare it, it shows up as undefined as nothing is being passed into it... Do you think trying to work with marionette will just solve this remove view issue... I appreciate your help and time by the way.

Comment: When a backbone view does not have an `el` property it will create an unattached element and render inside of it.  `this.$el` is the jQuery wrapper for that element, whether created or provided via `el`.  So in answer to your first question you do both, `$el.html(...)` in your render, which populates the `el`, which you then append to the page manually.  As to #2, the `options` I'm referring to would be your initialization options for the page view (model, collection, theId, and so on).  The difference is instead of passing them on creation, you pass them to `update` which sets them.

Comment: If you used marionette you'd probably make #Sirius into a region, which renders views inside of it.  This is essentially #1.  I actually use Marionette in a major project.  It has a lot of nice features, but also some bloat and its own issues, and it certainly adds complexity.  I'd suggest you get more comfortable with backbone before bringing in Marionette.  Honestly, not to knock marionette terribly, but removing it as a dependency has been on my list of todos for some time.

Comment: When including this $("#Sirius").html(page.el); the page does not load and it just appears blank but the #Sirius div exists. However, if I do the rest meaning if(page) ... then the #Sirius div disappears but it lets me render the page view once, and I console.log to view if the view exists and is being removed before a new page is added, and it does because the cid of the old view is view4 and then it shows remove called on view4 then view7 is created but i am not sure why the #sirius div disappeared and if I do include that one line it stays but no views render on it... I updated my code

Comment: Oh and when I do include the $("#Sirius").html(page.el); the if(page) does not even get checked but that is because the page does not even load... but if I move its position to above render the page does load once and then the same thing happens again where the view disappears... even the #sirius div disappears but it does look like the old view is being removed again..

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, but as I said in the answer and the related comment:  You ***need to remove the `el` from the page view definition (prototype)***.  If a Backbone view has an `el` it will render into it.  If it does not, it will create an unattached element, which you can add to the page wherever you want.  The latter is what you want.  The view should render into an unattached div, which you then insert into your container.  This view can then be removed from the DOM and cleaned up after without affecting the original page structure.

Comment: Look at this solution that I found that seems to work tell me if this is wrong... if (page) {console.log('page is current'); console.log(page); page.undelegateEvents(); page.$el.empty(); page.stopListening(); } either way works, I just tried your way and it works too, Im guessing your suggestion is better since everything is removed
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966440/recreating-a-removed-view-in-backbone-js pulled it from there... is that a good solution or should I remove it from the page view

Comment: That will work.  It's the first solution I proposed in #3, plus emptying the $el, which is kind of redundant since you're about to replace its contents.  #1 and #2 are arguably more appropriate.  #1 because this is probably the most traditional approach (rendering swappable views in a container) and #2 because it's more efficient (re-using the same view to display paginated content without needing to throw away and recreate the view and unbind/rebind events)